# How to remove UIView and add another UIView in appDelegate at runtime?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiapplicationdelegate, addsubview

I have 2 UIViews that are totally dependant on AppDelegate file.

First UIView is an Ad page that i have to launch when i start the app. But Already i have made the app with another HomeView that is dependant on AppDelegate.

I am adding AdView as follows in applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
[self.view addSubView:AdView.view];
```

But now I want that when i click **DONE** button in AdView page I should be navigated to HomeView. But homeView should be a subView of appDelegate

How can i write a code on **Done** button that will remove **AdView totally** and bring **Home View** as a subView of appDelegate??
thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in AdView , on button click event :

```
[self removeFromSuperView];
```

**EDITED**

As you want : remove AdView totally and bring Home View as a subView of appDelegate

I think you should create a method in delegate that removes your subview and add another subview to it. For that you need get reference of your delegate into the `AdView` and on button click call that delegate's method

```
- (void) methodInDelegate
{
   [AdView.view removeFromSuperView];
   [self performSelector:@selector(aMethodForAdding) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}

- (void) aMethodForAdding
 {
    [self.view addSubView:HomeView.view];
 }
```

Comment: ok then how can i insert new view as a subview of appdelegate view

Answer (score 1):

Use `removeFromSuperView` function of [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).

```
- (void)removeFromSuperview ;
```

Use as below ...

```
[AdView removeFromSuperView];
```

Comment: ok then how can i insert new view as a subview of appdelegate view.

Comment: Access the main view of your appdelegate  and add your home view. As below ... `[myAppDelegateView addSubView:HomeView]`